# sort two pair `std::pair<fs::path, fs::path>` in alphabetical order

Tags: c++, sorting, std

I am fairly new to C++ and I have two folders with the same number of files. I would like to sort both folders alphabetically and then print the filneame pairs:

```
[folder_1/file1.txt, folder_2/different_file4.txt] 
[folder_1/file2.txt, folder_2/different_file9.txt] 
[folder_1/file3.txt, folder_2/different_file35.txt] 
...
```

This is the code I wrote so far:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{ 
    cout << "C++ version: " << __cplusplus << "\n"; 
    
    const fs::path path_1{ "/home/path_to_folder1" };
    const fs::path path_2{ "/home/path_to_folder2" };
    std::vector<std::pair<fs::path, fs::path>> v{};
    std::transform(fs::recursive_directory_iterator{ path_1 }, {}, fs::recursive_directory_iterator{ path_2 }, std::back_inserter(v), [](auto& entry1, auto& entry2) {         
        return std::pair<fs::path, fs::path>{ entry1.path(), entry2.path() };
    }
    );
    // TODO: I need to sort, since directory iteration is not ordered on some file systems
    cout << "\n" ; 
    std:sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto &left, auto &right) {
    return left < right; // probably not needed for what I want (i.e., filenames sorted in alphabetical order) 
    cout << (left < right); // debug
    });
    for (auto& p : v)
    {
        std::cout << '[' << p.first << ", " << p.second << "]\n";
    }
}
```

I know I need to use the `std::sort` function but I can't seem to make it work.

EDIT:

expected output:

```
["/home/datasets/folder_1/file1.txt", "/home/datasets/folder_2/file432.txt"]
["/home/datasets/folder_1/file2.txt", "/home/datasets/folder_2/file456.txt"]
["/home/datasets/folder_1/file3.txt", "/home/datasets/folder_2/file556.txt"]
```

actual output:

```
["/home/datasets/folder_1/file1.txt", "/home/datasets/folder_2/file556.txt"]
["/home/datasets/folder_1/file2.txt", "/home/datasets/folder_2/file432.txt"]
["/home/datasets/folder_1/file3.txt", "/home/datasets/folder_2/file456.txt"]
```

Comment: whats wrong with the code you posted? If `fs::path` has a `operator<` (i dont know) then `std::pair` has one as well

Comment: It does not print the pairs in alphabetical order . I edited the code above, I don't know what to put in the condition of sorting to alphabetically sort both paths.

Comment: Perhaps you're surprised that `file10.txt` is *smaller* than `file2.txt`? That's because you do a [lexicographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order) comparison, not a numeric. You will get the same "problem" by just listing the files in a shell.

Comment: I don't think you need to specify the sorting criterion. But if you insist on using the condition, try `left < right`.

Comment: please include actual and expected output in the question

Comment: why did you vandalize your own question?!? The code was fine before, removing it makes the question worse...

Comment: now one can answer and say, just use `left < right` but we already know that thats not what you want. I am going to revert the edit....

Comment: Don't forget to use `const` in the lambda parameters! The code will be slightly more correct.

Comment: By the way, why are you using `printf` to print output? Why not simply `std::cout << '[' << p.first << ", " << p.second << "]\n";`?

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I really appreciate you taking the time to help. I am new to C++ and I might make a lot of mistakes. The `left < right` condition is not needed. I just need to have both folders filenams in alphabetical order. I edited my question taking into account your suggestions.

Comment: Do you understand that your "incorrect" sorting is, in fact, correctly sorted for how pairs are processed ? They're sorted by `first`, and only in the case of equivalence, they're sorted by `second`. This is coming from a file system, so `first` is very likely unique, therefore there will be no equivalence to send the comparison to `second`s. Keeping that in mind, look again at your actual output. It is clearly sorted by `first` correctly.

Comment: You're gathering the pairs (in some unspecified order) and then sorting those pairs lexicographically. It sounds like the effect you want is to sort each directory individually and then pair up the elements.

Comment: Have you looked at the *unsorted* data? Is e.g. `["/home/datasets/folder_1/file1.txt", "/home/datasets/folder_2/file432.txt"]` an actual pair in the unsorted data? To expand on the comment by @molbdnilo I think what you want is to create two vectors from of paths, sort each one separately, then transform both vectors into the single sorted vector you expect.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yes it is. I just created it while discussing with you to test on it.

Comment: Ok, now I'm dying to know. Assuming you fix this as prescribed and actually pull each directory iteration into separate vectors, sort them, *then* just merge them into a vector of 1-1 pairs, what is your supposition on what will happen in that transformation call if the second directory has *fewer* elements than the first ? I ask because it isn't going to end well if that is the case.

Comment: I am 100% sure that both directories will have the same amount of files. Otherwise, there MUST be an error. Anyway, I still have problems doing what you said. I will get back here as soon as I have a working code. Thanks again @WhozCraig

Comment: There must be an error is putting it mildly. If the first has more than the second, there won't just be an error; there will be *undefined behavior* and your program spins into la-la land. The second *could* have *more* than the first and things would still function. Anyway i suspect [this](https://godbolt.org/z/TGKjxMxYe) is what you're trying to ultimately do. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks again @WhozCraig, this is exactly what I was looking for. In the meantime I also was doing something similar [here](https://godbolt.org/z/qhTfcW8E3)